# how to show my mc in stage, Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have this in my public class :

```
public function SoyleDiagram(_Stage:Stage, startx:int, starty:int, 
                              bredde:int, hoyde:int, arrayen:Array)
```

but in my flash file i dont know what to wright in the `_Stage:Stage` spot

please help :D

Answer (score 0):

Your main class is some display object, so it has a `stage` property. By main I mean document class :) So there `this.stage` would be the stage that you need to pass.